# GTK user interface - best practice for text

Tags: user-interface, gtk

I look for tutorial GTK (text style for object: label, check box, box, etc)

For example best practice to set text (lowercase, uppercase, etc)
check box:

"Always ask me where to save files"
or
"Always Ask Me Where to Save Files"

lalels

etc

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A GTK+ style guide doesn't exist because GTK+ is just a toolkit: it could be used in several environments with different styles. That said, GNOME does have [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/unstable/) that are quite good and worth following. The part you're looking for is "[8.3.2. Text labels - Capitalization](https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/unstable/design-text-labels.html.en#layout-capitalization)".

Answer (score 1):

As A General Text Guideline, All Words Capitalized Is A Pain To Read, Especially For Longer Passages.

Use mixed-case instead with the first word and every proper noun capitalized. For example:

> [ ] Reiterate the commmon denominator of the Microsoft Vespa Extensions for Escherichia Bacteria at every reload.